# Haml::SyntaxError in Static#home?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, syntax-error

I have this Haml:

```
#index-header
  %h1 title
  %p motto
%h1 Our Software
  %p motto
.third-column
  %h2 Product 1
  %p foo
.third-column
  %h2 Product 2
  %p foo
.third-column
  %h2 Product 3
  %p foo
```

And I get this error:

> Haml::SyntaxError in Static#home
>
> Showing app/views/static/home.html.haml where line #5 raised:
>
> ```
> Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %h1 and nested within it.
> ```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's complaining because you have a `<p>` element inside an `<h1>` tag. (Line 4 in your code.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put content in a tag line, and add nested content at the same time.
Correct code:

```
#index-header
  %h1 Supersonic Mac Software.
  %p Some motto
%h1 
  Our Software
  %p Which will once becoume your's
```

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining because you have content on the same line as your `%h1` tag (`Our Software`) and nested beneath it (`%p Which will once becoume your's`), just like the error message says.

Answer (score 0):

If you, like me, were looking for a solution, but found a choir of naysayers in chorus. You will be happy to know that HAML is completely capable and equally willing to accommodate this requirement.

The focus of the error message rests on the words **on the same line** as haml needs all the content of a tag to be indented under its parent.

If we wanted the the example markup from this question to work as specified, we modify it as follows to produce the desired results without further complaints.

```yaml
#index-header
  %h1 title
  %p motto
%h1
  Our Software
  %p motto
.third-column
  %h2 Product 1
  %p foo
.third-column
  %h2 Product 2
  %p foo
.third-column
  %h2 Product 3
  %p foo
```

You may have noticed, we only needed to change the one `%h1` definition which has the nested `%p` tag, because this is the only definition violating HAML's parser.

By simply moving the content `Our Software` to an indented line alongside its peers, we effectively reduce cognitive friction making it clear that both items are siblings of the same parent.

The following snippet will produce the mark-up required for a [bootstrap 3 styled page header](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#page-header)

```yaml
.page-header
  %h1
    Example page header
    %small Subtext for header
```

nJoy!